# swipe-function does not work with my if-statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, swipe

```
(function(){
    if ($('#right-col').hasClass('shown')){
        $(this).swipe({
            swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                $(this).addClass('hidden');//.text(direction);
            }
        });
    }; 
})();
```

This is my swiping-function for a webproject i am working on. But somehow my code does not work with the if-statement. If i only use this:

```
$('#right-col').swipe({
  swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
    $(this).addClass('bg-blue').text("You swiped " + direction );
  }
})
```

It works fine. Can anyone tell me, whats especially wrong with my self-invoking-function above?

Comment: (this) won't trigger in an if statement like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `$(this).swipe(...)`, `this` is the `window`. Select the element using its id:

```
(function () {
    if ($('#right-col').hasClass('shown')) {
        $('#right-col').swipe({
            swipe: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                $(this).addClass('hidden'); //.text(direction);
            }
        });
    };
})();
```

Note that if the `#right-col` element's class changes later on, the swipe function won't be affected.

Comment: Yep, that solved my problem. Sometimes i still use the "this"-keyword wrong. But thank you for your help!

Comment: `this` in javascript can certainly be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

this is a little offtopic... but some time ago i wrote my own swipe function.

this function is mainly tested in ios devices.

1.creates custom events.

fc  = fastclick

swl = swipeleft

swr = swiperight

swu = swipeup

swd = swipedown

2.it's much faster than other swipes and you can use a simple pure js addeventlistener or attachevent.

3.it's written in pure javascript.

4.also the fastclick event allows you to click elements faster..

click = 400-500ms

fastclick = 40-50ms

```
window.onload=function(){
(function(d){
 var
 ce=function(e,n){var a=document.createEvent("CustomEvent");a.initCustomEvent(n,true,true,e.target);e.target.dispatchEvent(a);a=null;return false},
 nm=true,sp={x:0,y:0},ep={x:0,y:0},
 touch={
  touchstart:function(e){sp={x:e.touches[0].pageX,y:e.touches[0].pageY}},
  touchmove:function(e){nm=false;ep={x:e.touches[0].pageX,y:e.touches[0].pageY}},
  touchend:function(e){if(nm){ce(e,'fc')}else{var x=ep.x-sp.x,xr=Math.abs(x),y=ep.y-sp.y,yr=Math.abs(y);if(Math.max(xr,yr)>20){ce(e,(xr>yr?(x<0?'swl':'swr'):(y<0?'swu':'swd')))}};nm=true},
  touchcancel:function(e){nm=false}
 };
 for(var a in touch){d.addEventListener(a,touch[a],false);}
})(document);

// example
var h=function(e){console.log(e.type);};
document.body.addEventListener('fc',h,false);
document.body.addEventListener('swl',h,false);
document.body.addEventListener('swr',h,false);
document.body.addEventListener('swu',h,false);
document.body.addEventListener('swd',h,false);

}
```

here are more details on how you can use it..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17567696/2450730

it probably works also on android.