# JavaScript OnClick not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, browser, onclick, touchstart

I have developed code which detects when a user clicks on a cell in a table, and then uses the bgColor that has been set for that cell.

All works fine on the desktop computer, but when I try to use my iPad, it does nothing. I have tried to use touchstart but this had made no difference.

I tried changing this:-

```
 t[i].onclick = getVal;
```

to this:-

```
t[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function(){getVal});
```

But this has not worked....I will also need to support both desktop and touch devices....so not sure how I go about ensuring I support both in this situation.

My current code looks like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getVal(e) {
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;

    var colorSelected = targ.attributes.bgcolor.value;
    alert(colorSelected);
}
onload = function() 
{
    var ids = ['colorchart1', 'colorchart2', 'colorchart3', 'colorchart4', 'colorchart5'];
    for(var j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) 
    {
        var t = document.getElementById(ids[j]).getElementsByTagName("td");
        for ( var i = 0; i < t.length; i++ )
            t[i].onclick = getVal; 
    }
}

</script>



<table id="colorchart1">
<tr>
<td bgColor="#F8E0E0"></td><td bgColor="#F8ECE0"></td><td bgColor="#F7F8E0"></td><td   bgColor="#ECF8E0"></td>
<td bgColor="#E0F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8EC"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8F7"></td><td bgColor="#E0ECF8"></td><td bgColor="#E0E0F8"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td bgColor="#F5A9A9"></td><td bgColor="#F5D0A9"></td><td bgColor="#F2F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#D0F5A9"></td>
<td bgColor="#A9F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5D0"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5F2"></td><td bgColor="#A9D0F5"></td><td bgColor="#A9A9F5"></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Are you using any library?

Comment: No, not using jquery or anything, I prefer not to if possible, this is on a small embedded device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this handle function?

```
function handler(e){
 e.target.nodeName!='TD'||alert(e.target.bgColor+' on '+
 e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id);
}
window.addEventListener('click',handler,false);

or 

window.addEventListener('touchstart',handler,false);
```

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/gfmbkmmn/

with multiple tables

http://jsfiddle.net/gfmbkmmn/1/

the above function is an alternative solution to handle multiple tables with one event handler. to find your error more info is needed:

note: in ios is better that you write `window.onload`, and what about the `script` tags in your "current code", what does the getVal function?

if you have any questions about the code just ask

EDIT

```
function getVal(e){
 e=e||window.event;//not needed
 e.target=e.target||e.srcElement;//not needed
 if(e.target.nodeName=='TD'){// check if it's a td
  alert(e.target.bgColor);// why write  'targ.attributes.bgcolor.value' ?
 }
}
```

the node bug is from 7 years ago "Changed 7 years ago by ..."
 http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1148

js is case sensitive : `bgcolor != bgColor`

http://jsfiddle.net/gfmbkmmn/2/ this basic example allows you to create a fast color palette.

Comment: I've updated my question with the additional code as requested

Comment: if your developing for ios and other modern browsers... i would leave out all those target checks. did u try my demos??? if you want fastclick on ios http://stackoverflow.com/a/17567696/2450730 check cooments...

Comment: my function simplifies your code... there is no need for loops ...and all the stuff you have written. it can handle multiple tables and tells you the the current table id.

Comment: In your code, it triggers on every table, I need to make sure it only triggers on a select number of tables. Hence the array I created.

Comment: add a class to the triggerable tables... like <table class="colorbox"> then check for e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.classList.contains('colorbox') inside the getVal / handler function.....there is no need for loops. the e.target.nodeName=='TD' was just an example....we are here to help, give tips ... not to write everything. if you want to be specific you need to specify that in your question.

Comment: Tips are appreciated! I will give it a go from here...JavaScript is  not something I worked on before (well not for many many years), I spend most of my time with embedded C programming or iOS Objective C programmer, so I appreciate help from experts like yourself!

Comment: Thanks, all working now. I have marked up your posts and ticked answered