# What's the safest way to use FileReader with iOS8?

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, ios8, filereader

I have a form that has file selector. `<input type="file" ...` Run the code snippet below to see what it does.

On Safari on iOS8 there is [a known bug that means you cannot read file content with FileReader](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2014/09/10/ios8-presents-serious-issues-that-prevent-file-uploading/). This only happens on real hardware, the iOS simulator works fine.

On Chrome on iOS8 this code sometimes just completely crashes the browser.

I don't want to use agent sniffing to decide whether or not to attempt the function. Is there a better way to write this so that I can gracefully degrade to a simpler version?

```js
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var fileList = evt.target.files;
  
    for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        loadFile(fileList[i]);
    }
}

function loadFile(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += "file loaded: " + evt.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file); // broken in iOS8 && Safari
}
```

```html
<h2>Choose 1 or more files</h2>

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />

<h2>Loaded files will appear below:</h2>
<div id="list"></div>
```

It appears SO code snippets don't work on iOS so if you want to run the code, I've copied it to jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/zuyeteheroga/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can't you simply test `result.length`?

Comment: i think the filereader just works fine... but multiple uploads does not work correctly and gives you 0byte files... i solved the problem removing 'multiple="multiple"' .. naturally you can upload only one file... this on ios 7.

Comment: @Bergi, onload function is never invoked...

Comment: @cocco Removing the 'multiple' attribute made no difference on iOS 8. The 'onload' callback is never reached.

Comment: you also need to partially rewrite the functions without the multiple attribute... but nothing strange that apple's webapps do not work...they totally don't want to allow ppl to be able to create nice weapps.i keep ios 7 until i hear news about that, so i can't test further. they add alot of nice stuff in the releasenotes that don't work properly, and then remove those in the next ios version without updating the relasenotes.... had various similar problems... fullscreen, scroll, video, audio, streams, click..... bah.. it's just funny...

Comment: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios8-iphone6-web-developers-designers 'File uploads are broken!! Every file upload is not working, you can select a file or take a picture and after that JavaScript will not get any data, as well as the server on a POST upload through HTML or XMLHttpRequest upload. The problem doesn’t seem to apply for home screen webapps.'.... lol. bugs bugs bugs

Comment: also apparently the touch events have some bugs now http://stackoverflow.com/a/17567696/2450730

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the following to take a picture using the phone's camera and display it on the web page:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="image/*" onchange="inputFileChanged();" />
<img alt="The Picture" src="Content/1.jpg" id="imgDisplay" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    function inputFileChanged() {
        //alert("Input File Changed");
        var files = document.getElementById("fileInput").files;

        if (window.FileReader) { //Check browser - does it support File Reader?
            //alert("reader OK");
            loadImageFile(files);
        }
        else {
            alert("File Reader not Supported");
        }
    }

    function loadImageFile(files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (theImageElement) {
                return function (e) {
                    //alert("reader loaded");
                    theImageElement.src = e.target.result;
                }
            })(document.getElementById("imgDisplay"));
            reader.onerror = function (e) {
                alert("error " + e.target.error.code);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        } else {
            alert("no file");
        }
    }
</script>
```

On iPhone Safari iOS8, error code 4 (NOT_READABLE_ERR) is returned. 
This is a known bug (supposed to be resolved on next release).

No problems (so far) with Chrome on iPhone iOS8