# iOS 8.1.2 issue opening file -- Fixed

Tags: ios, filereader

## Problem

Greetings Stack Overflow community.
I have an issue with the iOS.

Currently, I am working in a web application with a mobile skin full responsive.
In the PC version everything works fine, same happening with android. Everything run's without any problem. But with the iOS I have some issues.

First, I had a bug with the file upload. I couldn't upload any file. I searched everywhere and then i find out that the version i was currently using had some serious problems with the file upload (iOS 8.0).

So I updated and now I have the 8.1.2 version. File upload its just working fine but now I can't see the pictures that I upload. The app returns me this:

- Open file;
- Open file with...;

I click in the options but nothing happens...

Could you please help me?

In advance thank you!

PS: It's an app with PHP/HTML/CSS. The normal web app style with a mobile skin.

## Solution

I found out the solution and I forgot to post.
The safari mobile browser and chrome mobile browser doesn't read pdf files however the desktop browser reads. So, I've made a new File Reader PHP Class and everything is now fixed. If anyone needs help please let me know, I'll have all pleasure to help.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Which app are you using? Where do you see "Open file" or "Open file with..."? It is unclear to me where you are having difficulty.

Comment: My bad, i am having this issue in iPhone 5S, running the latest version of Safari in the iPhone.
This issue happens after uploading an image. I click to preview the image, safari can't read and instead of downloading the image he does nothing. In chrome with my android he downloads the image and I can see the image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978111/whats-the-safest-way-to-use-filereader-with-ios8 
I think i found out the solution. I just couldn't find the solution because i wasn't properly searching for it.