# How to show scrollbar, after the user try scrolling?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hide the scrollbar, and then to show it again after the visitor try scrolling.
**HTML & JS**

```
<body onscroll="scrollable()" style="overflow: hidden;">
    ...
    <script>
    function scrollable() {
        document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
        /* If this makes any sense... */
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

**Snippet**

```js
function scrollable() {
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

```css
.enablescrolling {
  height: 10000px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="scrollable()" style="overflow: hidden;">
  ...
  <br>I didn't saw any errors in the console
  <div class="enablescrolling"></div>
```

Plese, help! Any ideas are welcome! I just can't solve it! This keeps from 2 days! Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What action(s) would you qualify as "scrolling" in the initial absence of a scrollbar? Mouse wheel? Down/Up arrows? Touch events? In any case, you'd need to listen for those events and apply the desired behavior accordingly.

Comment: Modifying overflow to hide scrolling everything user scrolls will adjust the page causing elements move left and right .

Comment: After applying overflow: hidden, scroll event will not fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great answer from Scott Marcus.

Another option would be to hide the scrollbar with a pseudo class `::-webkit-scrollbar` and then remove that class on scroll.

```js
function showScrollbar() {
  document.body.className = "";
}
```

```css
.enablescrolling {
  height: 10000px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.hideScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body onscroll="showScrollbar()" class="hideScrollbar">
  ...
  <br>I didn't saw any errors in the console
  <div class="enablescrolling"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Works! Thanks, but the pseudo ::-webkit-scrollbar will work only in webkit browsers.

Answer (score 2):

When the overflow is hidden, you can't scroll and if you can't scroll, there is no scroll event triggered and that's why your function isn't getting invoked.

You can listen for other events though, like the **[`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel)** event which triggers when the mouse wheel is rotated.

```js
document.addEventListener("wheel", scrollable);

function scrollable(evt) {
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

```css
.enablescrolling {
  height: 10000px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body style="overflow: hidden;">
  ...
  <br>I didn't saw any errors in the console
  <div class="enablescrolling"></div>
```

Comment: there is a problem that appeared later: touch screen devices. Any solution?

Comment: As I mentioned, you'll have to listen for other events. The `wheel` event is just one. For touch, it gets more complex. you'd probably also want to hook into `swipe` event of sorts, but one doesn't natively exist. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567344/detect-left-right-swipe-on-touch-devices-but-allow-up-down-scrolling

Comment: I saw the post, but this is getting too complicated to me - I am JS noob, for now. I am just gonna disable it at small screens, and I am currently adding option Settings, where the user can control stuff for the website.